# Serial Communication Between Android and Attiny85

Tags: serial, usb-device, logic-level, attiny85

I am planning to build a sensor module for smartphone using Attiny 85 as its microcontroller.

The sensor module will have a USB type A and to connect to the smartphone, OTG is required.

Serial Communication (TX RX) will be used for them to communicate with each other.

My questions are:

1. TX of Attiny85 should be connected to D+ or D-?
2. TX RX of Attiny85 will have 5V for its logic signal voltage
   level. Do I need to use a voltage regulator to change them to 3.3V
   for the D+ and D-? Commonly, what logic signal voltage level is used
   for D+ and D-?
3. What is the max current can be drawn from smartphone's USB

Note: My smartphone model is Redmi Note 4. TX RX of Attiny will be done by using software serial following this guide https://www.instructables.com/id/ATtiny85-ATtiny84-Analog-Pins-Serial-Communication/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) USB is not compatible with serial communications

2) USB is 3.3V levels so connecting 5V serial comms will kill your phone

3) 100mA without enumerating USB, maybe 500mA after requesting it.

Comment: Thank you for your fast and direct answer!
Appreciate it.
Regarding to your first answer, if USB is not compatible with Serial communication,then how it can be used to communicate with Arduino via Serial ?

Comment: In the link you posted, there is a board that has a FTDI USB to serial converter chip.

Comment: Thank you for the great input!